# Building a PL/SQL coverage report with DBMS Profiler

Tags: oracle, plsql, code-coverage, profiler

I am using [DBMS_PROFILER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_profil.htm) for basic profiling of my PL/SQL packages. I am also using it to get code coverage statistics using the following query:

```
SELECT EXEC.unit_name unitname,ROUND (EXEC.cnt/total.cnt * 100, 1) Code_coverage FROM 
    (SELECT u.unit_name, COUNT(1) cnt FROM plsql_profiler_data d, plsql_profiler_units u WHERE u.unit_number = d.unit_number GROUP BY u.unit_name) total, 
    (SELECT u.unit_name, COUNT(1) cnt FROM plsql_profiler_data d, plsql_profiler_units u WHERE u.unit_number = d.unit_number AND d.total_occur > 0 GROUP BY u.unit_name) EXEC 
    WHERE EXEC.unit_name = total.unit_name
```

I clear the plsql_profiler_data,plsql_profiler_units,plsql_profiler_runs tables before each profiler runs so that I need not know the run id each time.

This will give me Package wise information on the percentage of code that was covered during the profiling. Now I am trying to see if this can be built as a normal coverage report where I can know which line of code was covered and which one wasnt(say select lineOfCode, iscovered from...) so that I can built a report with html formatting to indicate if a line was covered or not.

I am not too proficient in Oracle table structures on where the functions and procedures get saved etc. (Got the above query from a blog and modified slightly to remove run id's)

Is this possible?

If so how can I achieve this?

Edit: This is not same as [Code coverage for PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152435/code-coverage-for-pl-sql)
I am already using DBMS Profiler. My query was on building the report.

Comment: See if this helps: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:458240723799

Answer (score 1):

I think this *approaches* what you're after:

```
-- View lines of code profiled, along with run times, next to the complete, ordered source..
-- Provides an annotated view of profiled packages, procs, etc.
-- Only the first line of a multiline SQL statement will register with timings.
SELECT u.UNIT_OWNER || '.' || u.UNIT_NAME AS "Unit"
  , s.line
  , CASE WHEN d.TOTAL_OCCUR >= 0 THEN 'C'
    ELSE ' ' END AS Covered
  , s.TEXT
  , TO_CHAR(d.TOTAL_TIME / (1000*1000*1000), 'fm990.000009') AS "Total Time (sec)"
  , CASE WHEN NVL(d.TOTAL_OCCUR, 1) > 0 THEN d.TOTAL_OCCUR ELSE 1 END AS "# Iterations"
  , TO_CHAR(CASE WHEN d.TOTAL_OCCUR > 0 THEN d.TOTAL_TIME / (d.TOTAL_OCCUR * (1000*1000*1000))
    ELSE NULL END, 'fm990.000009') AS "Avg Time (sec)"
FROM all_source s 
  LEFT JOIN plsql_profiler_units u ON s.OWNER = u.UNIT_OWNER
    AND s.NAME = u.UNIT_NAME
    AND s.TYPE = u.UNIT_TYPE
  LEFT JOIN plsql_profiler_data d ON u.UNIT_NUMBER = d.UNIT_NUMBER
    AND s.LINE = d.LINE#
    AND d.RUNID = u.RUNID
WHERE u.RUNID = ? -- Add RUNID of profiler run to investigate here 
ORDER BY u.UNIT_NAME
  , s.LINE
```

There are few issues to keep in mind.

1) Many rows in the `plsql_profiler_data` table will **NOT** have accurate values in their `TOTAL_TIME` column because they executed faster than the resolution of the timer.

[Ask Tom re: timings](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2468040431316#2513208067625):

> The timings are collected using some unit of time, typically only
>   granular to the HSECS.
>
> That means that many discrete events that take less then 1/100th of a
>   second, appear to take ZERO  seconds.
>
> Many discrete events that take less then 1/100ths of a second may
>   appear to take 1/100th of a  second.

2) Only the **FIRST** line in a multiline statement will show as covered.  So if you split an `INSERT` or whatever across multiple lines, I don't know of any easy way to have *every* line of that statement to show as profiled in an Annotated Source style of report.

Also, check out Oracle's [dbms_profiler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_profil.htm#sthref6972) documentation and [this](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_profiler.html) useful package reference for help crafting queries against the collected profiler data.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Will check this out but need couple of days time as Im held up with some deadlines. Will update you

Comment: Should i be having `WHERE u.RUNID = 2` in the query? There are no result if I have this where clause but when I removed it and u.RUNID=d.RUNID, I got IO error `ORA-01114: IO error writing block to file  (block # )`.

Comment: When I tried this ` select * from  all_source s 
  LEFT JOIN plsql_profiler_units u ON s.OWNER = u.UNIT_OWNER
    AND s.NAME = u.UNIT_NAME
    AND s.TYPE = u.UNIT_TYPE
  LEFT JOIN plsql_profiler_data d ON u.UNIT_NUMBER = d.UNIT_NUMBER
    AND s.LINE = d.LINE# AND d.RUNID = u.RUNID where total_occur is not null` I do get results. I did not null check as I saw some entries as null but with null check I also get 0. may be I need to to > 0. Any other optimization possible? I just need to know if a line has been covered or not

Comment: Sorry, the 2 in the query should be replaced by whatever the runid is of the run you want to investigate.  I'll update the query to make it clear that should be a bind value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are some tools for PL/SQL that do code coverage. See the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152435/code-coverage-for-pl-sql) for more information.

Said this, you can find information on user created data structure and code in following tables:

- `user_source`: here you can find the source in the `TEXT` field typified by function, procedure, package, etc.
- `User_tables`
- `user_indexes`
- `user_types`: if you use some kind of OO code.
- Other tables beginning with `user_` that you may need.

Basically you would need to check the result of your query against `user_source` and get extra information from the other tables.

Comment: most of the answers in that link points to DBMS_PROFILER, the query given is almost the same as the one I have shown in the question. The other 2 links didnt look very promising. Hence this question. Will check out user_source to see if it can be of help